# Justifying Visual Studio upgrade for REST API project

Tags: visual-studio

Our group does not primarily develop in c#/.NET, but a few years ago we picked up a couple of licenses for Visual Studio 2008 for a few projects.  Since we do not develop full time in .NET, we have not upgraded Visual Studio since then.

There is a project coming where we need to develop a web application that contains a REST API.  We have been looking at all of the documentation that deals with creating REST APIs. It appears that while VS 2008 is capable of creating APIs (with WCF), later versions of Visual Studio seem to have much better support for creating REST APIs ([ASP.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)).

My questions are:

1. Would upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 make that much of a difference in the development/maintenance of an API, or is Visual Studio 2008 sufficient?
2. How can we go about justifying an upgrade in our Visual Studio licenses (if needed)?
3. We don't want to justify an upgrade by just saying "it is newer so it is better".  Are there any documents that show how Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 is much better at creating REST APIs than Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: I'd like to piggy back onto this question a little and ask if 2008 is *good enough* to build a medium-complexity API?  I've read documentation that shows it is possible to build a REST API with 2008, but is it a good idea when newer versions are available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if is enough to justify the money but here are some reasons to adopt Visual Studio 2013:

- With Visual Studio 2008 you are restricted to .NET Framework 3.5 or lower. If you upgrade you have access to 4.0, 4.5 and future 5.0
- If you use Framework 4.5 you can use new [REST API Framework](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/08/rest-web-api).
- You can use latest versions of MVC.
- You can use latest Microsoft Entity Framework versions (old version can be used in Framework 3.5.1 but you really want the latest version as it has important performance improvement)
- You can benefit from [ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api).
- WCF was a way of improving web services, but not the best one. I would avoid WCF if possible.

**What is Web API?**

ASP.NET Web API is a framework for building web APIs on top of the .NET Framework. You can use the new MVC4 (ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project)

[image]

using Web API template.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cad - wondering if you could expand on your statement "I would avoid WCF if possible".

Comment: It is a subjective opinion. I worked a lot with WebServices and they were ok. Then I worked with WCF services and we had lots of problems, mostly our mistakes, like automated proxy classes were coming empty when recreating the proxy. Then I moved to restful services and were happy again. I think Restful is easy (KISS rule) while WCF was complicated and hard to learn...

Comment: Thanks @cad - that is a good explanation and works for me.  I'm still a bit lost on how to justify an upgrade, but your answer gives a bit more ammo.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

For me, it will always be a factor of the business side of things.  If they see the value, it is an easy sell.

If using Framework 4.5.1 (VS2013 required) will reduce both the server resources 
(See:

- ASP.NET application suspend
- Just-In-Time (JIT) performance of 15%
- "The .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows 8 introduce features that can help you achieve a significant performance boost for web-server workloads. This includes a reduction (up to 35%) in both startup time and in the memory footprint of web hosting sites that use ASP.NET."

)

AND bandwidth resources

(SEE:

- .NET 4.5 and WCF Request Compression
- http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/03/whats-new-in-wcf-v45.html under Compress and Cache
  ),

then one can actually do the maths and see if it makes sense already.  Then, the developer and maintenance side (which is quite "neat" in Vs2013 - new intellisense, nice nuget, etc.), is just jam.  From a developer point of view, you will also need to consider the cost to upgrade the application between versions, i.e. the cost from 2008 to vNext vs. 2013 to vNext.

Update:

As this is a very similar situation I find myself in, I have been doing some research.  Our company standards is VS2012 (RE: Microsoft Dynamics environment).

According to "What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2" at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) they suggest the following for your domain specific improvements:

•Ability to support multiple authentication modes on a single WCF endpoint when using the HTTP transport and transport security.

This is always a big seller for business.   Please look at the other improvements under WCF at the link above.

I have also found an article at http://www.msmsoftware.com/2013/8/6/the-business-benefits-of-upgrading-net-35-to-45.aspx that is very specifically aimed at your question.  They note, as I said, better performance, better security and increase development and support functions.

Your question is unique in that it targets the work side of things (WCF), so the fluff around better support for app stores, better web standards, etc. is somewhat pointless.   Hopefully I have given you enough to make the answer somewhat clear.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJr I have made some changes that you may be interested in.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get Visual Studio 2013 express for free and build all the web API's you'd like.  The paid versions include lots of enterprise features and plugin support.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx